# Transpose rows into columns help needed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to transpose multiple rows into columns.  However what I'm having to do is an overly complicated formula to get what I need.  Otherwise it's transforming column A, then Column B, then Column C and etc.  I need it to transpose the entire row, then go to the next row and transpose that one.

This formula is working for me:

```
=TRANSPOSE({AL3:AV3,AL4:AV4,AL5:AV5,AL6:AV6,AL7:AV7,AL8:AV8,AL9:AV9,AL10:AV10})
```

However there could be hundreds of rows on my sheet.  Is there a more simple formula for this?

Comment: I would suggest simplifying to ````=TRANSPOSE(AL3:AV10)````, but your formula will return only one column instead of multiple. Is this the intended output?

Comment: That doesn't work, I've done it the simple way.  It's not getting everything into one column.  That's why I had to do it this complicated way.

Answer (score 1):

try this formula:

```
=FLATTEN(AL3:AV)
```

Comment: No that doesn't work.  I'm trying to get all of the information into 1 column.  I tried that which is why I did it the more complicated way.

Comment: @LonestarDads can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Yes, here you go.  Look at Sheet2, Column Q:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1klyYY_fqekR4vHZND6ZPTABc8Tzh6sDqz8VslGmA8Zc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @LonestarDads see formula in Sheet2!S2 in your sheet